# I'm trying to identify this salamander-looking creature I found in my house today in Coos Bay, Oregon. It is about 2" long. What is it?

Tags: species-identification, species

[image][image]

This is about 2" long. It is white on its underside and looks like a small salamander, except for it being white underneath. It is about 1/8th inch wide.

Comment: Search for  Larch Mountain salamander *Plethodon larselli* images; some I found look similar but this is very rare endangered species and Coos Bay is a bit south of the reported range (Columbia river gorge and north) and it's mainly a mountain species.  Size is right, color approximately right.

Comment: The body form looks more like a skink than a salamander. Close to a 5-lined skink (https://www.wildlifedepartment.com/wildlifemgmt/swg/t35p1/WMA/E_fasciatus_AT.shtml) but those aren't native to OR>

Comment: @kmm I think you may be correct, looks like there are scales which aren't present in a salamander (and apparently salamanders usually have 4 front digits).  Searching for images of lizards/skinks for CA/OR/WA doesn't turn anything up, and each state has high quality web sites for herps.  Maybe it's a juvenile form that is not well documented?

Answer (score 2):

That is definitely a lizard, not a salamander. Salamanders don't have scales. It is a Northern Alligator lizard, *Elgaria coerulea*, in the family Anguidae.
https://www.inaturalist.org/check_lists/9307-Reptiles-of-Oregon
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_alligator_lizard

Comment: Is that typical coloration for the juvenile form?